# How to declare for loop in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Am getting error for "for loop".

```
FOR I IN 1 .. W_SPLIT_MSG.COUNT LOOP
```

My code is like this

```
IF W_SIM_VALI_REQ = 'Y' THEN
      IF position('@@@' in trim(both P_SIM_SL)) > 0 THEN
       --W_SPLIT_MSG := FN_SPLIT(trim(both P_SIM_SL), '@@@');
        W_SPLIT_MSG := split(trim(both P_SIM_SL), '@@@');
        FOR I IN 1 .. W_SPLIT_MSG.COUNT LOOP
        
          SELECT * FROM pkg_mobile_users_sp_check_imei(
              P_ENTITY_CODE,
              P_IMEI, 
              W_SPLIT_MSG(I), 
              P_OS, P_SUC_FLG, 
              P_ERROR, 
              P_ERROR_MSG) 
          INTO STRICT P_SUC_FLG, P_ERROR, P_ERROR_MSG;

          IF P_SUC_FLG = 'S' THEN
            RETURN;
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END IF;
```

But am getting error like

> FOR with integer loop variable* *record "w_split_msg" has no field "count"

But I have declared `w_split_msg` as:

```
W_SPLIT_MSG     SPLITSTR_TYPE;
```

Comment: More information is needed. Please post several surrounding lines of code (or full block) and the definition of SPLITSTR_TYPE at a minimum. All as formatted text - **no images**.

Comment: Postgres or Oracle? Why did you tag both?

Comment: I have posted several surrounding lines of code.

Comment: Pretty straight forward `w_split_msg` does not have attribute/field `count`. So this `split(trim(both P_SIM_SL), '@@@');` is not yielding what you think it is. A `RAISE NOTICE 'w_split_msg is %', w_split_msg;` would show what is being returned.  And per @Belayer we need to see the definition for `SPLITSTR_TYPE`.

Comment: where to declare count attribute. In "type"(SPLITSTR_TYPE type) or beginning of declaration

Comment: CREATE TYPE public.splitstr_type AS
(
 splitstr_type character varying(16000)[]
);     i have written like this "type" for splitstr_type

Comment: Please show a ***complete*** code block (or function if applicable) including all declarations, head and tail. And declare your version of Postgres